# How to add clothing to a rigged model

Tags: modeling

I'm making an avatar for a game called VRchat, I have a rigged model with armatures and that. (New user to blender by the way) but when I put on the clothing, and put it on unity, then to the game, the clothing doesnt actually move with the character, it just stays there. Ive been trying to fix this for a week now, but dont know how. The character is also to big for the clothing, as the torso sticks out, scaling the clothing isnt an option cause it ends up looking weird. Thanks. (I will probably only use blender for this one thing, so if its super simple, id be very grateful if someone could just do it for me quickly)

Comment: Have you parented the cloth to the armature? You can use Data Transfer to transfer the vertex groups from the body to the cloth by the way. I'm not sure how the cloth simulation work on Unity though, but in Blender you can't count on the physics only to move the cloth correctly, you need to parent to the armature.

Comment: I think it is a blender issue, im new to blender and I don't know how to. Would you just join the model and the clothes together?

Comment: You can keep them separated but you need to parent the cloth to the armature, have you done it?

Comment: I have heard of parenting, but have no idea on what to do, I selected the armature, then the clothes, and hit ctrl + p, but don't know what to do from there.

Comment: no it's the opposite, select the cloth, shift select the armature, Ctrl P > parent With Automatic Weights. If there are some problems, correct in Weight Paint mode, then join the cloth to the body with Ctrl J (it will keep the vertex groups)

Comment: thanks, that seemed to do something, but when I test it in the game, the actual character moves with animations, but the clothes are just in a tpose

Comment: did you join the cloth to the body?

Comment: thank you, that was very simple to do, I forgot to join it. but again for some reason its the same problem, I dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: hard to tell, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: im trying to share the file, but its not working.

Comment: or use workupload.com

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/Wvd5dHbab2U

Comment: reset the pose of your armature, as you see it's not a T pose, you should first correct the armature so that it's in T pose, also correct the body so that it is also in T pose, reparent

Comment: on mine it is all in a tpose?

Comment: no it is not, in Pose mode select all and press Alt R to bring it back to its rest pose, it would be better for a better parenting

Comment: Ive done everything youve said, multiple times, and yet is still doesnt work haha, I literally dont know what the problem is.

Comment: in Edit mode, you need to correct the armature so that it's in T pose, then correct the body as well to align it to the T pose, now you can parent the body, parent the cloth, join the cloth to the body